# What precisely is the distinction between Finnish /p k/ and /b g/?

Tags: phonology, phonetics

In Finnish /p k/ are formally voiceless, but in casual speech they can become fully voiced (Suomi et al), yet they are never mistaken for /b g/. What exactly is the distinction?